# Setting plot border frame for two subplot containing MatPlotLib.Basemap contents

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

As an illustration, I present  a figure here to depict my question.

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (10,4))
ax1 = plt.subplot(121)
map =Basemap(llcrnrlon=x_map1,llcrnrlat=y_map1,urcrnrlon=x_map2,urcrnrlat=y_map2)
map.readshapefile('shapefile','shapefile',zorder =2,linewidth = 0)
for info, shape in zip(map.shapefile, map.shapefile):
    x, y = zip(*shape) 
    map.plot(x, y, marker=None,color='k',linewidth = 0.5)
plt.title("a")
ax2 = plt.subplot(122)
y_pos = [0.5,1,]
performance = [484.0,1080.0]
bars = plt.bar(y_pos, performance, align='center')
plt.title("b")
```

[image]

Due to the mapping setting is not consistent with the subplot(b). Thus, subplot(a) and subplot(b) has distinct board frame. In my opinion, the un-aligned borders are not pleasant for reader.

Is there any way to adjust the boarder size of subplot(b) in order to harmony as a whole figure.

This is my target:

[image]

> Notice that, subplot(a) need to contain matplotlib.basemap elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, your subplot on the left has an `'equal'` aspect ratio, while for the other one it is automatic. Therefore, you have to manually set the aspect ratio of the subplot on the right:

```
def get_aspect(ax):
    xlim = ax.get_xlim()
    ylim = ax.get_ylim()
    aspect_ratio = abs((ylim[0]-ylim[1]) / (xlim[0]-xlim[1]))

    return aspect_ratio

ax2.set_aspect(get_aspect(ax1) / get_aspect(ax2))
```